# Apollo Angular2 client handling promise

Tags: angular, apollo, apollo-client

I have the below function is a service provider. I want to keep the back-end and UI part separate and so I use providers to fetch all data.

```
getUserById(id: number) {

return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
  this.apollo.query({
    query: UserByIdQueryText,
    variables: {
      id: id
    }
  }).subscribe((res: any) => {

    let ans = res.data.user;
    if (ans) {
      console.log(ans);
      resolve(ans);
    } else {
      reject('could not get user');
    }
  }, (err) => {
    console.error(err);
  });
});
```

}

In the actual page, I have the below code to fetch the data.

```
export class UserProfilePage {
  public user: User;
  public id: number;

  constructor(private userService: UserService, private navController: NavController, private params: NavParams) {
    this.user = null;
    this.id = params.get("id");

    this.userService.getUserById(this.id)
      .then((user: User) => {
        this.user = user;
      });
  }

}
```

The problem is that the remote call completes late but the view tries to show the data. I get the below error.

```
Error: Uncaught (in promise): TypeError: Cannot read property 'title' of null
TypeError: Cannot read property 'title' of null
    at Object.eval [as updateRenderer] (ng:///AppModule/UserProfilePage.ngfactory.js:273:28)
    at Object.debugUpdateRenderer [as updateRenderer] (http://localhost:8100/build/main.js:12978:21)
    at checkAndUpdateView (http://localhost:8100/build/main.js:12357:14)
    at callViewAction (http://localhost:8100/build/main.js:12667:17)
    at execComponentViewsAction (http://localhost:8100/build/main.js:12613:13)
```

Answer (score 0):

Regarding to your code. Could you provide some details about your database you are connecting?
I assuming you are using MongoDB as your backend data storage...
If so, this might be helpful:

```
getUserById(id: number, callback: (error: any, result: any) => void ) {
    this.apollo.find({"id":id}, callback);
}
```

This method should be used in server side inside your DAO object. Then you may use es6-promise to fetch the data from your client side service class. Like the following:

```
getUserById(id: number): Promise<any> {
    return this.http.get("someurl/" + id)
        .toPromise()
        .then((obj) => {
            //do your magic
        })
        .catch(() => {// handle your err});
}
```

Comment: I am using Apollo client which is related to GraphQL back-end data. I would like to use Apollo for fetching data...